# JUnit 4 - expect an Exception of a certain class, but not subclasses

Tags: java, junit

I'll try to provide a hackneyed, useless example that reduces the problem nicely :-)

I have a `GenericException`, and a `MoreSpecificException` which extends `GenericException`.

I need to test that `SomeService.doThis()` throws a `MoreSpecificException`. JUnit lets me do this elegantly like so.

```
@Test(expected = MoreSpecificException.class)
public void testDoThis() throws GenericException {
    new SomeService().doThis();
}
```

However, I also need to test that `SomeService.doThat()` throws a `GenericException`, so I tried this.

```
@Test(expected = GenericException.class)
public void testDoThat() throws GenericException {
    new SomeService().doThat();
}
```

However, I found that if `doThat()` actually throws a `MoreSpecificException` then the second test still passes. I assume this is because `MoreSpecificException` **is a** `GenericException` and the annotation is implemented to respect that relationship.

While this is a sensible default behaviour, *I don't want this*. I want to test that `doThat()` throws a `GenericException` and *only* a `GenericException`. If it throws a `MoreSpecificException` or any other subclass of `GenericException`, I want the test to fail.

Reading the [docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) it doesn't seem I can do anything with the annotation to change this behaviour, so looks like I'll have to use another solution.

At the moment I'm resorting to the following ugly solution - **EDIT *made significantly less ugly by Nathan Hughes' answer* :-)**

```
@Test
public void testDoThat() {
    try {
        new SomeService().doThat();
        Assert.fail();
    } catch(GenericException ex) {
        Assert.assertEquals(GenericException.class, ex.getClass());
    }
}
```

**Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I want within the JUnit framework?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [BDD](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/gwt.html) Style Solution

### [JUnit 4](http://junit.org/) + [Catch Exception](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) + [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core)

The most elegant solution ;) Readable, without boilerplate code.

```
@Test
public void testDoThat() {

    when(new SomeService()).doThat();

    then(caughtException()).isExactlyInstanceOf(GenericException.class);

}
```

The code is identical for [FEST Assertions 2](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki) + [Catch-Exceptions](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/).

### Source code

- https://gist.github.com/mariuszs/7489706

### Dependencies

```
org.assertj:assertj-core:1.4.0
com.googlecode.catch-exception:catch-exception:1.2.0
```

Comment: Ah, cool. Looking around I'm seeing a lot of people talking about using catch-exception to handle exceptions stuff - will look into this

Comment: This is better than catch-expection, this is combo with AssertJ :)

Answer (score 3):

You can assert that the class of the Exception is what you expect:

```
@Test
public void testDoThat() {
    try {
        new SomeService().doThat();
        Assert.fail();
    } catch(GenericException ex) {
        assertEquals(GenericException.class, ex.getClass());
    }
}
```

Also got rid of the flag, instead having the test fail if no exception is thrown.

Comment: Nice. That tidies that code up nicely - However I'm really looking for something baked into JUnit, rather than manually catching and checking the type of the exception, which I still think is ugly and could be abstracted away

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ExpectedException rule and a custom Hamcrest matcher that specifies which class can be thrown.

The following test will print that you expected an instance of RuntimeException, but got an IllegalArgumentException.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testThrows() {
    thrown.expect(isClass(RuntimeException.class));
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("FAKE");
}

public class ClassMatchMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Object> {
    private final Class<?> expectedClass;

    private ClassMatchMatcher(Class<?> expectedClass) {
        this.expectedClass = expectedClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        return expectedClass.equals(item.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("an instance of ")
                .appendText(expectedClass.getName());
    }
}

public class ExtraMatchers {
   public static Matcher<Object> isClass(Class<?> aClass) {
      return new ClassMatchMatcher(aClass);
   }
}
```

Edit:  Added a static factory method to make the test code cleaner.